# Why is my column component not being displayed as expected?

Tags: reactjs, row, react-bootstrap, col

I want to use `<Row>` and `<Col>` Components to arrange the content on my Website. However, the content is not being displayed as expected... :(

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my `App.tsx class`:

```
import "./App.css";
import DropdownMenu from "./components/DropdownMenu";
import TextBox from "./components/TextBox";
import { Component } from "react";
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';


interface AppProps { }

interface AppState { selectedCurrency: string }

class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> {

  constructor(props: AppProps) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { selectedCurrency: "EUR" }
  }

  private getData = (val: any) => { this.setState({ selectedCurrency: val.value }) }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DropdownMenu sendData={this.getData} defaultValue="Currency" values={[{ label: "EUR", value: "EUR" }, { label: "GBP", value: "GBP" }, { label: "USD", value: "USD" }]} ></DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownMenu sendData={() => ""} defaultValue="Coin" values={[{ label: "Bitcoin", value: "Bitcoin" }, { label: "Etherum", value: "Etherum" }, { label: "Cardano", value: "Cardano" }, { label: "Polkadot", value: "Polkadot" }, { label: "Litecoin", value: "Litecoin" }, { label: "Enjin", value: "Enjin" }, { label: "Chilliz", value: "Chilliz" }, { label: "Vetchain", value: "Vetchain" }]} ></DropdownMenu><br></br>
        <TextBox title="Coinbase" currency={this.state.selectedCurrency} avgPrice={200} volume={10000} marketcap={21000} backgroundColor="gray" height={100} width={300}></TextBox>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <TextBox title="Kraken" currency={this.state.selectedCurrency} avgPrice={200} volume={10000} marketcap={21000} backgroundColor="gray" height={100} width={300}></TextBox>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <TextBox title="Kraken" currency={this.state.selectedCurrency} avgPrice={200} volume={10000} marketcap={21000} backgroundColor="gray" height={100} width={300}></TextBox>
          </Col>
        </Row>
// NEW LINES START
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col>1 of 2</Col>
            <Col>2 of 2</Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
// NEW LINES END
      </div >
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

And here is the result:
[Output in my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnpbH.png)

Answer (score 0):

What I identify as the issue is that the width attribute of your `<Col>` is a the one of the `<Row>`.
In general this is happening when you forget the `<Container>`.

Try this:

```js
<Container>
  <Row>
    <Col>1 of 1</Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

So your code should be something like this:

```js
render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <DropdownMenu sendData={this.getData} defaultValue="Currency" values={[{ label: "EUR", value: "EUR" }, { label: "GBP", value: "GBP" }, { label: "USD", value: "USD" }]} ></DropdownMenu>
            <DropdownMenu sendData={() => ""} defaultValue="Coin" values={[{ label: "Bitcoin", value: "Bitcoin" }, { label: "Etherum", value: "Etherum" }, { label: "Cardano", value: "Cardano" }, { label: "Polkadot", value: "Polkadot" }, { label: "Litecoin", value: "Litecoin" }, { label: "Enjin", value: "Enjin" }, { label: "Chilliz", value: "Chilliz" }, { label: "Vetchain", value: "Vetchain" }]} ></DropdownMenu><br></br>
            <TextBox title="Coinbase" currency={this.state.selectedCurrency} avgPrice={200} volume={10000} marketcap={21000} backgroundColor="gray" height={100} width={300}></TextBox>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <TextBox title="Kraken" currency={this.state.selectedCurrency} avgPrice={200} volume={10000} marketcap={21000} backgroundColor="gray" height={100} width={300}></TextBox>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <TextBox title="Kraken" currency={this.state.selectedCurrency} avgPrice={200} volume={10000} marketcap={21000} backgroundColor="gray" height={100} width={300}></TextBox>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean, the `.` is missing ?? 
I implemented the following: 
``` 
<Container>
          <Row>
            <Col>1 of 2</Col>
            <Col>2 of 2</Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
```
however, the columns are still displayed underneath, not next to each other

Comment: I don't see the <Container> in your example.

Comment: Yes, that's correct it wasn't there. I added the lines from my previous comment underneath. I'll edit my original post to demonstrate where :)

Comment: Please don't forget to mark it as solved if this solution works for you.

Comment: it doesn't though :( The columns are still underneath each other, not next to each other as desired...
Am I being stupid and missing something again? xD Thanks for taking the time to answer :)

Comment: I edited my response. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I'm sorry but that changed extactly zero about the way the content is placed on the page.

Comment: This is a working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gfzs8?file=/src/App.js